# Typescript error: Property 'children' is missing in type but required in type 'CommonProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

First time seeing an error like this so please bear with me.

I was working on a project and opened one file to make a change. I opened the file, didn't actually make any change and just formatted the file using Prettier.

Right when it formatted, the project threw the error below:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/name/source/repos/UsedEquipment/src/pages/listings/sections/SearchResultListings.tsx(253,16):
Type '{ style: { height: string; }; type: "rect"; ready: false; showLoadingAnimation: true; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & CommonProps & { color?: string | undefined; rows?: number | undefined; showLoadingAnimation?: boolean | undefined; customPlaceholder?: undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }) | ... 4 more ... | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & { ...; })'.
  Property 'children' is missing in type '{ style: { height: string; }; type: "rect"; ready: false; showLoadingAnimation: true; }' but required in type 'CommonProps'.  TS2322
```

Here's the code where the error's thrown:

```
showPlaceholders() {
    let items: Object[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ITEMSPERPAGE; i++) {
      //show # of placeholders
      items.push(
        <div
          className="productwrap col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 placeholder"
          key={i}
        >
          <div className="product-wrapper">
            <div className="product-image">
              <ReactPlaceholder
              ^ Error thrown here
                style={{ height: "180px" }}
                type="rect"
                ready={false}
                showLoadingAnimation={true}
              ></ReactPlaceholder>
            </div>
            <div className="product-info-column">
              <ReactPlaceholder
              ^ Error thrown here
                type="text"
                rows={6}
                ready={false}
                showLoadingAnimation={true}
              ></ReactPlaceholder>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return items;
  }
```

I'm not entirely sure what this error means or how to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: Please pass  <p>This is a Test.</p> inside ReactPlaceholder then try. I think ReactPlaceholder is asking for child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[React Placeholder expects one child component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-placeholder). Pass in any valid html tag inside it.

```
<ReactPlaceholder { /*...your other optional props */ }>
  <MyComponent /> {/* this is mandatory */ }
</ReactPlaceholder>
```